# Active directory user's password expire when never login

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

Is there any way to expire password when a user never logins for 3 0r 4 days in active directory.Basically user cant login when user absent for 3 or 4 days.

Answer (score 1):

That's way too short an interval - what about public holidays or if someone is sick? Also, knowing the logon time for all accounts across multiple DCs is painful in anything but a small environment.

But you can create a script that will DISABLE the accounts **after** 14 days based on LastLogonTimeStamp, which means you don't need to query every DC for every user. You can't use that attribute for checking logons **under** 14 days.

Comment: If you liked my suggestion, please mark it as an answer or upvote it.